# InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': HTTP Request with Intermediate Model and service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an angular app which consists of a form which sets the fields of a model object and then the object itself is sent as JSON to my backend. However whenever I try to use the following approach with image/file upload, I get an error:

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
Error: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.setProperty
```

How can I get past this? Also, I cannot try change the approach of the Form so please try and suggest something within this approach.

html

```
<mat-toolbar>Avatar/Logo</mat-toolbar>
            <input type="file" id="my-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event) [(ngModel)]="temp_file">
```

.ts

```
  onFileSelected(event){
    this.temp_file = <File>event.target.files[0];
    this.detail.logo = this.temp_file;
  }
```

details.model.ts

```
export class Detail {
...
    logo: File;
...
}
```

Comment: remove the ngModel part -  [(ngModel)]="temp_file" - and it should work

Comment: The error is no longer there but the image doesn't get sent in the response. @Moshezauros

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the `[(ngModel)]`, then, append the `this.temp_file` the form when uploading it to the server, here is a sample code for the service.ts which does the http post:

dsds

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File, formData: FormData): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = 'your-destination-url';
    formData.append('my-input', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.httpClient
      .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: yourHeadersConfig })
      .map(() => { return true; })
      .catch((e) => this.handleError(e)); 
}
```

`fileToUpload` is `temp_file` which is sent from the component to the service.